# Print full stress tensor in ASE to calculate Green Kubo viscosity

Tags: python, atomic-simulation-environment, stress-strain

I would like to print out the off diagonal components of the full stress tensor in ASE. The goal is then to calculate the Green Kubo viscosity. One should use the ensemble average of the off diagonal stress tensor.

**Q1: Should I use the cell stress or the per-atom stress?**

I am trying different calculators (`GPAW`, `EMT` and `XTB`) but none is able to print `atoms.get_stresses()`. They all give me this result: `stresses property not implemented`.

**Q2: Is there a way to print out the full stress tensor in ASE?**

**Q3: Is there a table that lists which calculators can output it?**

Please find an example with water in PBC below.

Thank you

```
from ase import Atoms
import ase.build


# EMT
from ase.calculators.emt import EMT
calculator = EMT()

# XTB
from xtb.ase.calculator import XTB
calculator = XTB(method="GFN0-xTB")

# GPAW
from gpaw import GPAW, PW
calculator = GPAW(xc='PBE', mode=PW(300), txt='h2o.txt')

atoms = ase.build.molecule('H2O')
cell_size = 2.8
atoms.set_cell([cell_size, cell_size, cell_size])
atoms.set_pbc([True, True, True])

# Apply the calculator
atoms.set_calculator(calculator)
print(atoms)
print(calculator)
print(atoms.get_stress())
print(atoms.get_stresses())
```

```
Atoms(symbols='OH2', pbc=True, cell=[2.8, 2.8, 2.8], calculator=GPAW(...))
<gpaw.calculator.GPAW object at 0x7f72944f3d00>
[0.66560263 0.53795715 0.54856487 0.         0.         0.        ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mdi0316/WORK_TME022/PGEL/forum_questions/print_stresses.py", line 68, in <module>
    print(atoms.get_stresses())
  File "/home/mdi0316/miniconda3/envs/pgel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/atoms.py", line 865, in get_stresses
    stresses = self._calc.get_stresses(self)
  File "/home/mdi0316/miniconda3/envs/pgel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/abc.py", line 32, in get_stresses
    return self.get_property('stresses', atoms)
  File "/home/mdi0316/miniconda3/envs/pgel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/calculator.py", line 724, in get_property
    raise PropertyNotImplementedError('{} property not implemented'
ase.calculators.calculator.PropertyNotImplementedError: stresses property not implemented
```

Comment: Regarding your specific code example, the EMT, XTB, and GPAW calculators you mentioned do not have built-in support for accessing the full stress tensor using the atoms.get_stresses() method. The error message you encountered indicates that the property is not implemented for those calculators.

Comment: You already answered your question in your question. You don't get stresses from those calculators simply because `stresses property not implemented`. If you want to get stresses, you can use e.g. a Vasp calculator which has stresses implemented.

Comment: Thank you both, but I don't have a Vasp license. Which brings to the second question, is there no way of getting a list of calculators with the stresses property implemented? Also isn't stress = stresses.sum()? How can they print the cell stress and not know the individual stresses? Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASE, but if you use `Quantum ESPRESSO` as a calculator it has stresses as an option. See https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/calculators/espresso.html

Comment: also QE gives `PropertyNotImplementedError`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but do you really need `get_stresses()`? This particular function gives per-atom stresses, which are usually only defined for classical potentials. The full stress tensor of the system (including off-diagonal elements) is returned by the `get_stress()` method, which is available for most calculators (ASE uses the Voigt convention, so 6 components are output).

Comment: @KristofBal thank you for your suggestion. In the GK formula you need the ensemble average, which should be above all atoms. So I believe that, by using the `stress`, I take the average inside the summation going from \Sum <P_ab(t)P_ab(0)> to \Sum <P_ab(t)><P_ab(0)>, which is true only for non correlated systems.

Comment: @KristofBal is correct. Note that you can return a 3x3 matrix instead of the Voigt form by using `atoms.get_stress(voigt=False)`. Kinetic contributions to stress can be included with `include_ideal_gas=True`.

I would be very surprised if the viscosity coefficient would require atomic stresses. I had a look at AllenTildesley to confirm that this is indeed not the case. I would recommend to carefully check the theory.

Comment: Thank you @flokno, but then on what do I average? Looking at the lammps example here https://docs.lammps.org/Howto_viscosity.html, you print all atomic stresses and you average on it.

Comment: The quoted LAMMPS example uses pxy, pxz, pyz, which are the off-diagonal global stresses (not per-atom). For per-atom stresses, LAMMPS has the `compute stress/atom` command.

Comment: As discussed elsewhere: Ensemble average here means multiple replicas of the simulation cell, i.e., multiple simulations for statistically independent starting conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to all the comments and parallel discussions, I realised that to calculate Green Kubo viscosity one has to use the stress tensor. From Allen Tildesley, p61:

> These quantities [the stress tensor] are multiple particle properties, [...], and no statistical averaging is possible.

**A1** Thus, I should effectively use the stress tensor from `get_stress()` and not `get_stresses()` as initially thought.

**A2&3** ASE does not ensure that a given calculator implements and benchmarks high level properties. Thus one has to check time to time whether a calculator has a property implemented